# Setting Typescript --module compiler option in WebEssentials?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

I am unable to install Typescript on Vis Studio 2012.  It says it's installed, but there's no Add-in or Extension.  Luckily, Web Essentials will compile Typescript.  These are very nice products.

I want to generate a Typescript external module (for AMD) but there's no place to set the --module option.  Web Essentials has options, but they're all True/False.  And since the VSIX doesn't install I have no Build rules to modify.

If I add a Typescript 'export' I get:
        TS5037: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.

Is there someplace I can control Web Essentials compiler options from??  For that matter, I can't ever find documentation on compiler options.

Thanks

Comment: You won't be able to rely on Web Essentials much longer for TypeScript as it is being removed to avoid clashes with new Visual Studio support. Maybe we can help you to get the extension working?

Comment: I have gone thru the Install / Repair / Uninstall cycle, both reg. and as Admin.  I have one project where I get intellisense and another nothing.  Neither show an TS extension.

Answer (score 1):

Tools - options - webessentials - typescript - module : amd

Having said that I rely on grunt to do my compilation : https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts

Comment: that sounds like the option I need.  WE 2.9 (8/23/13) doesn't have the option -- maybe it's dependent on TS vsix installing.  Thanks for pointing out Grunt.

Comment: For the visual studio plugin check out the support here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18424265/390330