# TypeScript 0.9.* VisualStudio TS5037: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided

Tags: module, typescript

I do get the TypeScript compiler error **TS5037: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.**

I am using **TypeScript 0.9.1.1** und **Visual Studio 2012**.

Where can I set the **--module** option in Visual Studio?
Web Essential seems to no longer support this option in the dialog.

Thankx, Harry

Update:
I have a configuration file (config.ts) for my project. This file contains many statements as the following:

```
export var loggedInUserId: number = 0;
```

There are no other statements as the one before. Do I have to define a **class** or **module** around it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was having this problem in Visual Studio 2013, even with that setting above set correctly. It turns out there's a project-level setting as well. If you go to Project Settings on the project with TypeScript (highlight the project and type Alt+Enter), then go to the TypeScript Build tab, and select AMD under "Module System"

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can find the option for non project files here (Tools - options - Editor - TypeScript):

[image]

For my project based work I use grunt : https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts

Comment: Thankx Basarat. I have set this option, but I still get the same behavior. The files I am working with are "part of the project"; the option says that it is for modules that are not part of a project...

Comment: Yeah, I guess you will need to manually modify the visual studio project file (sigh)

Comment: What are the modification I would have to do?

Comment: Here are the options you can use to customize `TypeScriptCompile` build task : https://msbuildtypescript.codeplex.com/ inside your visual studio project.

Comment: Wau... this seems all quite a "handy job". I would have assumed that this is going much easier ;-) ... Thank you very much for your inputs!

Comment: Thanks basarat!  I use Gulp and I needed to do this in order to get that pesky error message to go away.  I ended up checking the box, selecting AMD, then unchecking the box.  Oddly enough, that made the error go away